# App force closes when find for location by GPS

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling, logcat

Hi i am getting a force close everytime i run my application.. it allows the splashscreen to appear, but as soon as i click on 'Find My Location' button it forces close.... the thing i'm finding strange is that is works fine with wi-fi when my gps is turned off.. I have checked to ensure the i have the right permissions in the manifest also. I've attached the logcat. Am i assuming right by this the error is in MyLocOverlay class on line 23? Could someone please point me in the right direction for fixing this? 
Thanks

```
public class MyLocOverlay extends Overlay {
    private final int Radius = 5;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if (shadow == false) {
            // line below is line 23
            Double lat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
            Double lng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
            GeoPoint geoPoint; geoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(),lng.intValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-14 02:41:30.332: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.irwine.touristapplication/.SplashScreen }

04-14 02:41:30.502: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Start proc com.irwine.touristapplication for activity com.irwine.touristapplication/.SplashScreen: pid=13759 uid=10060 gids={3003}

04-14 02:41:31.012: WARN/Rosie(5927): mAddHtcWidgetByOtherActivity = false, mIsOpenSlideWhenLeaveLaunch = true

04-14 02:41:31.012: WARN/InputManagerService(102): Ignoring hideSoftInput of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44b033b8

04-14 02:41:31.132: WARN/InputManagerService(102): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 13731 uid 10060

04-14 02:41:31.322: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Displayed activity com.irwine.touristapplication/.SplashScreen: 834 ms (total 33041 ms)

04-14 02:41:36.152: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.irwine.touristapplication/.mainmenu }

04-14 02:41:36.542: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Displayed activity com.irwine.touristapplication/.mainmenu: 337 ms (total 337 ms)

04-14 02:41:40.152: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.irwine.touristapplication/.gps }

04-14 02:41:42.502: INFO/MapActivity(13759): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED

04-14 02:41:42.502: ERROR/MapActivity(13759): Couldn't get connection factory client

04-14 02:41:42.752: WARN/dalvikvm(13759): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028a00)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759): java.lang.NullPointerException

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.irwine.touristapplication.MyLocOverlay.draw(MyLocOverlay.java:23)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.google.android.maps.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:179)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:45)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-14 02:41:42.802: WARN/ActivityManager(102):   Force finishing activity com.irwine.touristapplication/.gps

04-14 02:41:42.812: WARN/ActivityManager(102):   Force finishing activity com.irwine.touristapplication/.mainmenu
04-14 
02:41:43.316: WARN/ActivityManager(102): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44eb0130 com.irwine.touristapplication/.gps}

04-14 02:41:44.742: INFO/Process(13759): Sending signal. PID: 13759 SIG: 9

04-14 02:41:44.752: INFO/WindowManager(102): WIN DEATH: Window{44b42110 com.irwine.touristapplication/com.irwine.touristapplication.mainmenu paused=true}

04-14 02:41:44.762: INFO/ActivityManager(102): Process com.irwine.touristapplication (pid 13759) has died.

04-14 02:41:44.772: INFO/WindowManager(102): WIN DEATH: Window{44b66298 com.irwine.touristapplication/com.irwine.touristapplication.gps paused=false}

04-14 02:41:53.654: WARN/ActivityManager(102): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44bd91e8 com.irwine.touristapplication/.mainmenu}

04-14 02:41:53.699: WARN/ActivityManager(102): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44eb0130 com.irwine.touristapplication/.gps}
```

Comment: Please format the post, its hard enough to read your error.

Comment: @IrishGal: "Am i assuming right by this the error is in MyLocOverlay class on line 23?" - Probably. Post your code for MyLocOverlay.

Comment: Also a small code snippet would help too...

Comment: public class MyLocOverlay extends Overlay {

 private final int Radius = 5;
 
 @Override
 public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
  Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
  
  if (shadow == false) {
   // line below is line 23   Double lat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
   Double lng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
   GeoPoint geoPoint;
   geoPoint = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(),lng.intValue());

Comment: Just encase the entire error in a code block.. click the "{}" button after highlighting the block, and then it should be fine. However check out my response.

Comment: @IrishGal Instead of adding the code snippet as an unformatted comment, edit your original post, and use the code formatting tools provided. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Jason LeBrun ahhh thanks Jason :)

Answer (score 1):

You say you have the right permissions. Just to be sure, you know that there are two different permissions for location?

String  ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  Allows an application to access coarse (e.g., Cell-ID, WiFi) location
String  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION    Allows an application to access fine (e.g., GPS) location

[Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: yes i have both in as i want to use the best provider to give me a more accurate location

Comment: It can't be a permission error, it would complain in the log if that was the case. Good try though :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is important**

```
EXCEPTION: main 04-14 02:41:42.782: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759): java.lang.NullPointerException 

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13759):     at com.irwine.touristapplication.MyLocOverlay.draw(MyLocOverlay.java:23)
```

if I had to guess, I'd say that your location is null. Try running in debug mode and see what you can find. My suggestion is put a break point BEFORE the error line and look at what the variables are.. if your location variable is null, that is your problem, way to fix this is to keep pinging until you get it..

The solution is to check if the location is null.. if its null, then this means you need to request the location again. If you try pinging for 20s and don't get anything, keep pinging until you get something. Ideally you want it to time out after 5 tries... **This is because if you ping constantly the user will hate you**. However; If 100s pass and you don't get a location, then time out and have the user request that location again or ask them to try again later.

**UPDATE**

Specifically, i see an error with this. Here is how I would approach it:

Request the location -> Wait for the location through the location listener -> Once the locations received then update the overlay.

Keep requesting as long as the location returned is null. Time out like I said.

Here is an example:

my LocationListener class:

```
public class myLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        Location L;

        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location has changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            L = arg0;
            updateNewLocation(L);
        }}
```

Function I call:

```
public void updateNewLocation(Location loc) {

        // while the location is not null get latitude and longitude
        // information
        // :: Null means that the GPS provider is off or there is an issue
        if (loc != null) {}}
```

Function body I use to request location along with timeout:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Searching for your location.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 5,
                            locationListener);

                    // Thread to count until timeout (15 * 5000ms)
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            count = 0;

                            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                                if (locationListener.L == null) {
                                    try {
                                        handler.sendMessage(handler
                                                .obtainMessage());
                                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
```

Handler to help with timeout

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            count++;
            if (count == 15) {
                error();
                count = 0;
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: @JoxTraex i dont understand how the location can be null because when i run it with gps turned off and wifi turned on, it fixes the location on the map.. this has been puzzling me for hours. Sorry about the code snippet above

Comment: @@JoxTraex: What has 'ping' got to do with obtaining a location via GPS?

Comment: I may be using it out of context, but for me pinging would involve the action of 'requesting' the location from the GPS.

Comment: @JoxTraex thanks so much for your help but i dont totally understand.. i have an if statement in for when the location is not null to display the location.. is there any reason that im gettin a location using wifi or cell towers and it forces closes with gps? I really appreciate your help. im a newbie :)

Comment: @IrishGal Just because you request a location does NOT mean you will recieve it. The way GPS works is it works out your location through requests. When it has enough information it then alerts android that it has your location and your location listener would recieve the brand new location. Sometimes it may take several requests before you actually get the new accurate location.

Comment: @IrishGal specifically the only reason it would crash is because if you TRY to get the geopoint from the location WHEN it is null.. it would through a nullpointer exception. , So what this means is.. You request, set your time out, wait for the location. When you recieve the location your location listener will call a method called "onLocationRecieved" or something like that. This is called when it has your location.

Comment: Do a check when the location is null.. The error is because the location variable is null.

Comment: @JoxTraex Yes i have a location listener method set up to when a location is changed / or found that it calls the updateLocation method.

Comment: @JoxTraex yes if the location is passed in as null it should display a message saying no address found

Comment: Then do something about this, if its null.. then do nothing but keep requesting until its not null.